# Event Handler Not Setting State Before Component Renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Component renders with initial state before state is updated.

The initial state is null and onHandlePrint method updates the state when the button is clicked.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    pdf: null,
  };

  updatePDF = (data) => {

  }

  onHandlePrint = (pdf) => {
    this.setState({pdf}, () => {
      this.updatePDF(this.state.pdf)
   })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Router>
          <ActivityDetail results={this.state.results} clickPrint={this.onHandlePrint} />
          <Switch>
            <Route 
              path="/pdf" 
              render={() => (
                <PDFDocument data={this.state.pdf} />
              )} 
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

The button is a Link using  to open a new tab that will render a PDF document with the data passed into the event as the "obj"

```
const ActivityDetail = ({ results, clickPrint }) => {

  const renderedList = results.map((obj, index) => {

    return (
      <li key={index}>
        <div className="service-container">
          <Link to="/pdf" target="_blank" className="print-button-container">
            <button 
              className="print-button" 
              onClick={() => clickPrint(obj)} 
            >Print</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {renderedList}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ActivityDetail;
```

This is the PDF document that should get the data when the Print button is clicked but props is undefined.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  section: {
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
    flexGrow: 1
  }
})

const PDFDocument = (props) => {

  const { NameOfService } = props

  console.log('props:', props)
  return(
    <PDFViewer className="pdf-viewer">
      <Document>
        <Page size="A4" style={styles.page}>
          <View style={styles.section}>
            <Text>
              {NameOfService}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    </PDFViewer>
  )  
}

export default PDFDocument
```

**EDIT**

So what I know have is a callback to a method that handles the newly set state.

```
onHandlePrint = (pdf) => {
   this.setState({pdf}, () => {
      this.updatePDF(this.state.pdf)
   })
  }
```

My new question is how do I send that data from the updatePDF method to the component ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not `setState` within a `setState` callback function.  Instead it should return the new state.  This:

```
onHandlePrint = (pdf) => {
    this.setState({pdf}, () => {
      this.setState({pdfStatus: true})
    });
  };
```

should be:

```
onHandlePrint = (pdf) => {
    this.setState(() => {pdf, pdfStatus: true});
  };
```

But really if you don't need to use previous state you don't need to use a callback.  Just do:

```
onHandlePrint = (pdf) => {
    this.setState({pdf, pdfStatus: true});
  };
```

Comment: Initially my code didn't have the pdfStatus state. Edited my post. The problem I have is the PDFDocument component props of data is undefined when rendered.

Answer (score -1):

Use  `async` & `await`

```
onHandlePrint =  async (pdf) => {
    await this.setState({pdf}, () => {
        this.setState({pdfStatus: true})
    });
};
```